# R Modify the class DIFFTIME to hist

Tags: r, histogram, difftime

In my script I have transform this data.frame as shown:

```
df.modified<-transform(df, new.col= Payment.date-Selectionfinal$Invoice.Date)
```

This is the result:

```
    Client.Code. Invoice.Date Payment.date  new.col
1:      1004850   2016-01-31   2016-11-22 296 days
2:      1004850   2016-06-30   2016-11-22 145 days
3:      1004850   2016-06-30   2016-11-22 145 days
4:      1004850   2016-06-30   2016-11-22 145 days
5:      1004850   2016-09-30   2016-11-22  53 days
```

Then, i need to plot it into an histogram, but I have this problem:

```
> hist(df.modified[,c(4)])
Error in hist.default(Completo[, c(4)]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

This is the str of my df:

```
$ Client.Code.: int  1004850 1004850 1004850 1004850 1004850 1004850 1004850 1004874 1004874 1005133 ...
$ Invoice.Date: Date, format: "2016-01-31" "2016-06-30" "2016-06-30" "2016-06-30" ...
$ Payment.date: Date, format: "2016-11-22" "2016-11-22" "2016-11-22" "2016-11-22" ...
$ new.col     :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:4430] 296 145 145 145 53 53 53 102 72 71 ...
```

Please i will like to know the trick for that. Thank you.

Comment: `hist(as.numeric(df.modified[,c(4)]))`

Comment: I tried this before: (> hist(as.numeric(df.modified[,c(4)]))
Error in hist(as.numeric(df.modified[, c(4)])) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double')

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguez Do you still need a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kristofersen already pointed out, the problem is in the type of what you pass as data to `hist` function. The data is expected to be `numeric` and does not accept `difftime`.

```
# some data mimicking your data
Client.Code. <- c(1004850, 1004849, 1004850, 1004850, 1004851)
Invoice.Date <- as.Date(c("2016-01-31", "2016-03-30", "2016-06-30", "2016-06-30", "2016-04-30"))
Payment.date <- as.Date(c("2016-11-22", "2016-10-22", "2016-09-22", "2016-08-22", "2016-10-09"))
# creating the new column in a similar way to your way
df <- data.frame(Client.Code., Invoice.Date, Payment.date)
df$new.col <- df$Payment.date - df$Invoice.Date

## the following 3 do not work because they pass difftime to hist()
hist(df[,c(4)])
hist(df[,4])
hist(df$new.col)

# class of difftime
class(df$new.col)

## these 3 do work: numeric is passed to hist()
hist(as.numeric(df$new.col))
hist(as.numeric(df[,4]))
hist(as.numeric(df[,c(4)]))
```

Comment: HI, KoenV, as I said before, i´ve tried this before the question:

Comment: Hi, Alvaro, I have run and tested my code. It works fine for me.